# Git Extensions possible

Tags: git, plugins

I was recently wondering if there was a way to write a plugin for git which checks all files during the staging of the files. For example if someone tries to add a code file with no comments in it the staging or commit would be refused, therefore trying to train the user in his coding behaviour.

Would you have to do this server side or would that be an extension to the git bash and if so do you any good guides on it?

Comment: You're looking for [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit). See [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pre-commit+hook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are referring to git hooks - check [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Let me know if you require some examples